# What is the best way to shift a multidimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a javascript function that shifts an array right x units any up y units. It must keep the array size the same, and it must call unloadChunk for elements that are getting shifted off the multidimensional array. Here is my current implementation:

```
function shift(x, y) {
    if (x > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
            for (var j = chunks[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(j + x > chunks[i].length - 1 && chunks[i][j]) {
                  unloadChunk(i, j);
                } 
                if (j < x) {
                    chunks[i][j] = null;
                }
                else {
                    chunks[i][j] = chunks[i][j - x];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (x < 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < chunks[i].length; j++) {
                if(j + x  < 0 && chunks[i][j]) {
                  unloadChunk(i, j);
                } 
                if (j - x >= chunks[i].length) {
                    chunks[i][j] = null;
                }
                else {
                    chunks[i][j] = chunks[i][j - x];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (y > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
            if (i + y >= chunks.length) {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
                  if(i - y < 0 && chunks[i][j]) {
                    unloadChunk(i, j);
                  }
                  chunks[i][j] = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
                    if(i - y < 0 && chunks[i][j]) {
                      unloadChunk(i, j);
                    }
                    chunks[i][j] = chunks[i + y][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (y < 0) {
        for (var i = chunks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i + y < 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
                     if(i - y > chunks.length - 1 && chunks[i][j]) {
                       unloadChunk(i, j);
                     }
                    chunks[i][j] = null;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++) {
                     if(i - y > chunks.length - 1 && chunks[i][j]) {
                       unloadChunk(i, j);
                     }
                    chunks[i][j] = chunks[i + y][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're having trouble understanding exactly what I want the shift function to do, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brianhoy/j18w4fdh/2/) and look at the html output.
My attempt at creating the shift function works, but it has 10 for loops. My question was, is there a more efficient, less verbose way to do this?

Comment: do you like to keep the same size of the arrays? or just append by moving right, a `null` in front?

Comment: @NinaScholz Keeping the same size of the arrays is important because in my case I'm filling all the null values with new values. Sorry for not mentioning that in the post, I'll edit that now.

Answer (score 3):

This proposal uses

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): visit each item
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): return value for each item
- [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop): removes and return last element
- [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push): adds one or more elements at the end
- [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift): removes and return first element
- [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift): adds one or more elements at the beginning

For better visibillity, I replaced the `null` value with `1000`, `2000`, `3000` and `4000`.

```js
function shift(x, y) {
    while (x > 0) {
        chunks.forEach(function (a) {
            a.pop();
            a.unshift(1000);
        });
        x--;
    }
    while (x < 0) {
        chunks.forEach(function (a) {
            a.shift();
            a.push(2000);
        });
        x++;
    }
    while (y > 0) {
        chunks.unshift(chunks.pop().map(function () { return 3000; }));
        y--;
    }
    while (y < 0) {
        chunks.push(chunks.shift().map(function () { return 4000; }));
        y++;
    }
}

function print(msg) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';
}

function printarr(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        print(JSON.stringify(arr[i]))
    }
}

var chunks = [[5, 3, 1], [9, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7]];

print("chunks: " + JSON.stringify(chunks));
shift(1, 0);
print("shifting right 1. chunks: "); printarr(chunks);
shift(-1, 0);
print("shifting left 1. chunks: "); printarr(chunks);
shift(0, 1);
print("shifting up 1. chunks: "); printarr(chunks);
shift(0, -1);
print("shifting down 1. chunks: "); printarr(chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop()`, `push()`, `shift()`, `unshift()` Array methods

```
var chunks = [
  [5, 3, 1],
  [9, 2, 5],
  [2, 3, 7]
];

function shiftDown(){
  chuck.pop();
  chuck.unshift(Array(3));
}

function shiftUp(){
  chuck.shift();
  chuck.push(Array(3));
}

function shiftRight(){
  chuck.foreach(function(v){
    v.pop();
    v.unshift(null);
  })
}

function shiftLeft(){
  chuck.foreach(function(v){
    v.shift();
    v.push(null);
  })
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it can't handle shifting multiple units at once. To shift right two units, you while have to call shiftRight() twice.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`, [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var chunks = [[5, 3, 1], [9, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7]];
// `x`: Index at which to start changing array
// `y`: An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove
function shift(arr, x, y, replacement) {
  arr.forEach(function(curr, index) {
    // The elements to add to the array, beginning at the start index.
    // start index: `x` 
    curr.splice(x, y, replacement) 
  });
  return arr
}
// e.g.,
shift(chunks, -1, 1, null);
console.log(chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

> it must call unloadChunk for elements that should be set to null

it's not a good idea to mutate an Array, while you're iterating over the same Array. So change `unloadChunk()` to not change `chunks`, but return the new value.

> in my case I'm filling all the null values with new values.

then why do you bother to insert the `null`-values in the first place? why don't you just insert the new values?

```
//one-dimensional shift
function shift(arr, offset, callback){
    var i, j, len = arr.length;
    if(len && (offset |= 0)){
        typeof callback === "function" || (callback = function(v){return v});
        if(offset < 0){
            for(i=-offset,j=0; i<len;)arr[j++]=arr[i++];
            while(j<len)arr[j]=callback(null,j++,arr);
        }else if(offset){
            for(i=len-offset,j=len; i>0;)arr[--j]=arr[--i];
            for(i=0; i<j;++i)arr[i]=callback(null,i,arr);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

//two dimensional shift
function shift2d(matrix, offsetX, offsetY, callback){
    var i, len = matrix.length, tmp, fn;
    offsetY |= 0;
    offsetX |= 0;
    if(len && matrix[0].length && (offsetY || offsetX)){
        typeof callback === "function" || (callback = function(v){return v});
        fn = function(val,j){ return callback(null, [i,j], matrix) };
        tmp = {length: matrix[0].length};
        offsetY && shift(matrix, offsetY, function(){return tmp});
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            if(matrix[i] === tmp){
                matrix[i] = Array.from(tmp,fn);
            }else{
                shift(matrix[i], offsetX, fn);
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

and the code:

```
var chunks = [[5, 3, 1], [9, 2, 5], [2, 3, 7]];

console.log(chunks);
console.log(shift2d(chunks, -1, 1));
console.log(shift2d(chunks, 1, -1, computeValue));

function computeValue(value, index, array){
    console.log("value: %o index: %o, is chunks: %o", value, index, array === chunks);

    //return the new value for this field
    return JSON.stringify(index);
    return Math.random();

    //with ES6 array destructuring:
    var [row,col] = index;
    return row*3 + col;
}
```

`shift()` and `shift2d()` expect as the last argument an (optional) callback function that **returns** the new values.
For consistency reasons, I pass the same argument as *Array.map* and the others

- *value*:  always `null`, only there for consistency reasons
- *index*:  the "index" that is accessed. For `shift2d` this is an array of indices (take a look at [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring))
- *array*:  the current array/matrix. Don't mess around with this while it gets changed. The main reason to pass this argument, is to check wich Array you're currently processing.

Comment: Sorry! I mis-worded that. I edited the OP again to be worded correctly: it must call unloadChunk for elements that are getting shifted off the multidimensional array. My previous implementation was causing problems for me because for some reason, I thought that elements that were getting set to null were being sent of the multidimensional array. To provide some background, I'm using this as a chunk manager for my three.js game, and as the player moves into new chunks, it should shift the chunks array in the opposite direction and generate new chunks by filling the null values with new chunks.